# Unable to Start Pentaho on Ubuntu Server

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

Getting below error while starting Pentaho Server

DEBUG: Using PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME

DEBUG:_PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java

Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/pentaho/pentaho-server/tomcat

Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/pentaho/pentaho-server/tomcat

Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/pentaho/pentaho-server/tomcat/temp

Using JRE_HOME:        usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

Using CLASSPATH:       /home/pentaho/pentaho-server/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/pentaho/pentaho-server/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar

Tomcat started.

Comment: There are no errors on what you’ve posted, just debug messages, ending with a “Tomcat started”, which seems to indicate it’s all normal. However, if you’re running Pentaho 8.2 you may want to switch to openjdk.

Comment: @nsousa- But still I am unable to access port 8080.
Error is connection refused. I have tried to access 8080 locally using curl as well.

Comment: check tomcat/logs/catalina.out. Your errors will be there.

Comment: Thanks @nsousa.
I can see below error message, I am running a 1 GB RAM server. Can you pls suggest the RAM size for Pentaho to run?

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000640000000, 715784192, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 715784192 bytes for committing reserved memory.

Comment: @nsousa - Finally, I was able to start Pentaho after upgrading the server RAM.
Thanks for the guidance to find the root cause.

Comment: Use 4gb at least.